# Negating literal strings in a Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

So regular expressions seem to match on the longest possible match.  For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "ClarkRalphKentGuyGreenGardnerClarkSupermanKent";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Clark.*Kent", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher myMatcher = p.matcher(s);
    int i = 1;
    while (myMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(i++ + ". " + myMatcher.group());
    }
}
```

generates output

1. ClarkRalphKentGuyGreenGardnerClarkSupermanKent

I would like this output

1. ClarkRalphKent
2. ClarkSupermanKent

I have been trying Patterns like:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Clark[^((Kent)*)]Kent", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

that don't work, but you see what I'm trying to say.  I want the string from Clark to Kent that doesn't contain any occurrences of Kent.

This string:

ClarkRalphKentGuyGreenGardnerBruceBatmanKent

should generate output

1. ClarkRalphKent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

greedy vs reluctant is your friend here.

try: `Clark.+?Kent`

Answer (score 4):

You want a "reluctant" rather than a "greedy" quantifier. Simply putting a ? after your * should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

When you tried `"Clark[^((Kent)*)]Kent"`, I think you were wanting `"Clark((?!Kent).)*Kent"` for [zero-width negative look-ahead](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) (scroll down a bit to the "Look-Around Assertions" header).

Brackets specify character matching vs. pattern matching. So, the RegExp was trying to find a single character not in `(, K, e, n, t, ), *`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the relunctant `?` suffix: `Clark.*?Kent`
The quantifiers `?`, `*`, `+` can be followed by `?` to indicate that they should stop as soon as possible.

see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html